# I have single cluster 2 node datacenter, while doing replication testing i make 1 node down then i getting error by running nodetool status command

Tags: cassandra

I have single cluster 2 node datacenter, while doing replication testing by making 1 node down and trying to connect cqlsh in other node getting the below error.

Also, I have checked the consistency level is ONE.

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Error during authentication of user cassandra : org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM"',)})

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `cassandra` user for authentication. It's not recommended to do, as it's a special user, and its authentication always happens with `QUORUM`. It's better to create a separate user (or super user) for accessing the Cassandra, and don't use `cassandra`. See [DataStax documentation for more details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/5.1/security/Auth/secCreateRootAccount.html).

Just:

- make sure that all nodes are up
- check that `system_auth` keyspace is replicated to multiple machines (in your case it's 2 - see [docs for detailed instructions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/5.1/security/secSystemKeyspace.html))
- if you changed the replication factor, run repair to replicate data to all nodes
- create the new user(s)